# why the weights do not update in pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

Im quiet new to pytorch and want to design a simple nn.
However when running the code below, the nn seems to not learn anything.

I designed the same nn with tensorflow, and the accuracy quickly converges to 1.
Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import os
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch import optim
import torch.nn.functional as F


class HSVData(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, path_to_data) -> None:
        self.x, self.y = self._load_data(path_to_data)

    def _load_data(self, path_to_data):
        with np.load(path_to_data) as f:
            fx, fy = f.files
            x, y = f[fx], f[fy]

            x = torch.from_numpy(x)
            y = torch.from_numpy(y)

            y = self._to_categorical(y, torch.max(y).item()+1)
            return x, y

    def _to_categorical(self, y, num_classes):
        return np.eye(num_classes)[y]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.y)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.x[idx], self.y[idx]


class NNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.nn_stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_dim, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, output_dim),
            nn.Softmax(dim=1))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.to(torch.float32)
        return self.nn_stack(x)


def train(model, dataloader, loss_fn, optimizer):
    model.train()
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        pred = model(x)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y.to(torch.float32))

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()


def val(model, dataloader):
    model.eval()
    correct = 0, 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for x, y in dataloader:
            pred = model(x)
            correct += 1 if (pred.argmax().item() == y.argmax().item()) else 0

        print(f"Accuracy: {100*(correct/len(dataloader))}")


dataset = HSVData("data/5k_per_point.npz")
train_data, val_data = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [44000, 11000])

train_dl = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)
val_dl = DataLoader(val_data, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)

model = NNModel(8, 11)
loss_fn = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

epochs = 5
for e in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {e+1}\n-------------------------------")
    train(model, train_dl, loss_fn, optimizer)
    val(model, val_dl)
```

To provide more informaton:

Feature Vector:

```
tensor([0, 3739, 4095, 2243, 3077,  518, 2208,  939], dtype=torch.int32)
```

Ground Truth:

```
tensor([0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=torch.float64)
```

Prediction:

```
tensor([[5.3249e-44, 0.0000e+00, 6.5020e-16, 0.0000e+00, 1.4795e-11, 0.0000e+00,
         8.1166e-10, 1.0000e+00, 1.7702e-36, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00]],
       grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward0>)
```

--> The Accuracy stays constant at 8.xx ~ percent, which I would expect if the nn is randomly guessing.

Comment: Why are you using a binary cross-entropy, are you doing a multi-label classification?

Comment: Yes, my label is one-hot encoded (11 classes).

Comment: Did you check the convergence of the loss function on train and test dataset?

Comment: Then, why are you not using a [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.10/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html?highlight=crossentropy#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) module?

Comment: @Ivan that question i really cant answer, I calculated the values for both [torch.nn.BCELoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html) and [torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) and could not find the difference between the two losses, except for crossentropy using a additional softmax.

Comment: This is not the reasoning you should have. If you don't know why you are using such a function, then you need to look into in more deeply.